# Socket not saving data inside handshake object?

Tags: javascript, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to save session data inside a `handshake` object from `io.set('authorization')`

```
var io = sio.listen(server);
io.set('authorization', function (handshake, callback) {

  if(handshake.headers.cookie) {

    var cookies = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie);
    var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(cookies['xygaming'], secrets.sessionSecret);

    sessionStore.load(sid, function(err, session) {
      if(err || !session) {
        return callback('Error retrieving session!', false);
      }

      // this is not storing the data into the handshake object
      handshake.balloons = {
        user: session.passport.user,
        room: /\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/g.exec(handshake.headers.referer)[1]
      };

      return callback(null, true);

    }); 

  } else {
    return callback('No cookie transmitted.', false);
  }
});
```

I have an adapter for pub sub

```
io.adapter(redisIo({ 
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 6379,
  pubClient: pub, // just redis.createClient()
  subClient: sub // just redis.createClient()
}));
```

Then I want to access the handshake data inside the `io.sockets.on('connection')` but its not there? Any idea why its not passing? In the original repo it works on express 3x, but since I upgraded to 4x and made some modifications of my own it does not pass through?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log(socket.handshake);
  // I want to pass the handshake data here, but its undefined??
  var hs = socket.handshake
    , nickname = hs.balloons.user.username
    , provider = hs.balloons.user.provider
    , userKey = provider + ":" + nickname
    , room_id = hs.balloons.room
    , now = new Date()
    // Chat Log handler
    , chatlogFileName = './chats/' + room_id + (now.getFullYear()) + (now.getMonth() + 1) + (now.getDate()) + ".txt"
    // , chatlogWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(chatlogFileName, {'flags': 'a'});
  socket.join(room_id);

});
```